# How to add ajax reference in asp.net?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-3.5

suggest me, Is that all ajax resource files are necessary?

look at the screenshot when i add an ajax dll to web app it adds all resource files(boxed with RED color)

can remove all the resource files? they may cause problem?

reply me guys...

Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1767272.aspx/1?Is+Ajax+resource+files+are+needed+or+AjaxControlToolkit+dll+alone+in+my+web+app+

Answer (score 4):

Right Click the References in Solution Explorer and select Add Reference,Select "Browse" Tab, Select AjaxToolkit.dll from the "bin" folder from your project folder.

Comment: thanks for writing... but i asked you something you have given me something... also i marked an answer there.

Comment: I reply to your question "How to add ajax reference in asp.net?". My answer is "straightforward" and may useful for other user in future.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me as well.  I was getting a "ajaxcontroltookit.toolkitscriptmanger is not defined" error message, but everything had been working.  This cleared the error.